# CA-Signed Certificates

Tags: certificates, api-client-certificate

We are looking to integrate Salesforce with a web service using 2 way SSL.  One of the requirements is that we have the certificates CA-signed.

1. Can we use the same certificates across multiple sandboxes
2. We are also looking to setup a custom URL which requires a CA-signed certificate - can we reuse this for the integration?

Answer (score 3):

You can use one CA signed certificate in multiple places as long as that CA signed certificate is valid and can be used in authentication by external system.

You can export CA certificate in .jks format from one sandbox and import it in any sandbox.

https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_certificates.htm